# How can I make an request params to mongo db from node js and swagger?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, swagger

What I have tried is to get all the data by `createdBy` param. `createdBy` has a user phone number value.

controller

```
exports.getLocation = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const createdBy = req.params.createdBy
    console.log('created', createdBy) // its empty 

    const getLocation = await Location.find( {createdBy: createdBy} )

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        msg: "Getting all the locations of the user",
        data: getLocation
    })
})
```

routes

```
 /**
 * @swagger
 * /location/getLocation/:createdBy:
 *   get:
 *     summary: getting the location of the user by phone number
 *     tags: [Location]
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: false
 *       content:
 *        application/json:
 *          schema:
 *            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Location'
 *
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: the location has been recivied
 *       500:
 *         description: Some server error
 */
  router.get("/getLocation/:createdBy", getLocation)
```

The idea is to put the param in a request body, to get all the data of the `createdBy` key in the database. The get method doesn't accept a request body.
How can I put a param so I can get the data from the database?

To let you know, I'm using the swagger request body to execute the API, and this API is for a react-native application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct your swagger annotation for `createdBy` property,

- use `{createdBy}` instead of `:createdBy` in URL
- use `parameters` property of swagger and in that declare the `createdBy` property with `path` type
- `requestBody` is not required because you are using `GET` request type

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /location/getLocation/{createdBy}:
 *   get:
 *     summary: getting the location of the user by phone number
 *     tags: [Location]
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: createdBy
 *         description: Created By
 *         in: path
 *         required: true
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: the location has been recivied
 *       500:
 *         description: Some server error
 */

router.get("/getLocation/:createdBy", getLocation);
```

Comment: I get the response 200, but the data is empty.                                                                       ```{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "Getting all the locations of the user",
  "data": []
}```

Comment: Also when I ```console.log(createdBy)``` it shows this in the terminal: ```created {createdBy}```